# How to zip files/directories in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, zip

I would like to zip a folder containing files and subfolders in VB.NET.  My solution targets .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

I see that there is a ZipFile class for .NET 4.5, and System.IO.Packing for .NET 4.0 (but not Client Profile).  So, those won't help.  I note that there is also a GZipStream class, but I never see .gz files floating around, so not sure if that's a good approach.  I would prefer a basic .zip file that I know my users can work with.

There are a handful of third-party solutions, such as http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/, but I assume they are far more bloated than the 10-20 lines of code I am looking for.  Maybe that's the right answer...I don't know.

Just hoping for a few lines of VB.NET code to zip some files in a solution targeting .NET 4.0 CP.

Comment: Uh, why the down vote?  Is this not a valid question, or is this retaliation from contributors who clearly did not read the question before submitting their answers?

Answer (score 7):

Create ZIP from "source" folder.

```
Imports System.IO.Compression    
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("source","destination.zip",CompressionLevel.Optimal,False)
```

Extract ZIP to "destination" folder.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("destination.zip","destination")
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be sample code or a set of instructions? Either way, you should add more detail to your answer explaining what is happening and why it needs to be done, as well as take the time to properly format your answer using SO's Markdown variant.

Comment: Is there a way to give as different path For eg: Source in C:\ drive and destination in D:\ drive. I tried a lot. It gives me an error saying root folder cannot be changed. Is there a work around to browse in which destination I want the zipped file (including different drives like from C:\ to D:\ or E:\  like any user selection)

Answer (score 4):

Unable to comment in the comments section due to lack of reputation (due to being new here).

On the two answers indicating that *using System.IO.Compression* can be used that were commented as not working in NET 4.0 CP, this should be noted, as the original answers did not include an often overlooked fact.

A reference needs to be added to the project in order to activate "System.IO.Compression".  This is not obvious to many new VS users, and unless the refrence is added, it indeed seems like "System.IO.Compression" does not work in NET 4.0.

In this case, the reference that needs to be added is **System.IO.Compression.Filesystem** (v4.0.0.0).  One may also wish to add the reference: **System.IO.Compression**.

The "Add Reference..." dialog is under the "Project" menu in VS.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why i didnt have the ZipFile class :)

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN Website has a class that can help you out here called [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```js
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
      string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
      string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";
      'Creates Zip File to directory as specified (startPath). And puts it in a specifed folder (zipPath)
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
              '
      Extracts Zip File to directory as specified(extractpath)
      ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it using [Ionic.Zip.Dll](http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/ionic_zip_dll.html)

Here is the function for this,accepting two variables source path and destination path

```
public static void ExecuteBackupAsZip(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
        {
            using (var zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
            {
                try
                {
                    zip.AddDirectory(SourcePath);
                    zip.Save(DestinationPath);
                }
                catch { Console.WriteLine("Failed to execute backup"); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think I would download something from such an unscrupulous-looking website.  If you have the source for the DLL in VB.NET, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Same challenges as "an odder guest". That is can't commment due to low rep as new user and have to add a new answer. (Frequent reader though). Running on vb.Net 4.6 and got no errors on the suggestions above, but no output zip file was generated. Then after some googling added references **System.IO.Compression.Filesystem** and **System.IO.Compression** and ended up with the following one-liner:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(FilePath1, FilePath3_ZippedFile)
```

Where FilePath1 is the path to the source folder (c:\whateverfolder) and FilePath3_ZippedFile is the path to the resulting output zip-file(c:\anotherfolder\MyZipFile.zip).

Sorry if you think my input is redundant, but I know for newcommers like my self we need the answers feed with tee spoons.

**Word of caution:** If you try to create the zip-file in the source folder you might have issues. My code then only included one of the files from the source folder in the zip-file. (No error messages). Changing the target location to another folder solved this without other edits to the code.

Comment: Is there a way to give as different path For eg: Source in C:\ drive and destination in D:\ drive. I tried a lot. It gives me an error saying root folder cannot be changed. Is there a work around to browse in which destination I want the zipped file (including different drives like from C:\ to D:\ or E:\ like any user selection)

Comment: I've not tried what you are asking for Priya, but a workaround might be to zip to a C folder, and then move to final target destination drive and folder if there isn't any practical issues preventing that.

Comment: Yes.. I used the exact same work around.. I did not find much options to directly zip into other drive folder.. So had to stick with this. Even moving to other drive was a problem. It was easy to move with in same drive. Finally solved it using `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(src_filename, dest_filename)`